# Catching and Throwing an Exception: What happens "under the hood"?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am not familiar with error/exception handling. 
What is happening "under the hood" when an exception is `caught` and `thrown`?

I.e. what is the point of catching an exception in a try-catch block, then throwing it?

E.g:

```
  try {
        //Stuff
    } catch(StuffException e) {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the inner workings of the exception mechanism: There is plenty of documentation on this.
I'm particularly a fan of this article:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076868/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-exceptions.html

Ultra-short summary: When an exception is thrown, the jvm looks up in a table where the execution (of the init() method of the exception) continues.

For the second part of your question:

> what is the point of catching an exception in a try-catch block, then throwing it?

I see some reasons for catching an exception an throwing another one:

- You might want to catch an unchecked exception (because you know,
  "something bad might happen") and throw a checked one - so the caller has to handle it.
- You want to use a custom Exception, maybe with additional
  information/logic
- You're Implementing an error facade, e.g. throwing exceptions and
  catching them at the end in the facade.

Comment: Link-only questions are considered low-quality. The link may break at some point. So you should include a summary of its content in your answer.

Comment: I don't see the point in replicating the article, so I've just added an ultra short summary - in addition I've seen I didn't answer the second part of the question - hope I fixed that.

Comment: "so the caller has to handle it." > I am not sure what this means, I.e. how does a caller handle an error. I have not got a strong grasp of error handling.

Comment: It means that, when you throw a checked exception in your method, the part of a program that uses your method has to catch your exception, or it won't even compile (usually the IDE gives you a hint to surround it with a try-catch block).

Answer (score 2):

Your example catches something with the type of StuffException, then throws a MyException. This is done to abstract away the original exception; it might be that the original exception is an implementation detail that the thing calling it doesn't need to know about (and which needs to be able to change, so that the caller shouldn't depend on it), and the exception thrown to replace it is part of the published API, which the caller can depend on. This is the case with Hibernate, it catches SQLExceptions generated in the course of calling JDBC functions, and wraps them in Hibernate exceptions, so calling code recognizes them as being thrown from Hibernate, and calling code doesn't depend directly on the JDBC exceptions, but on Hibernate's. If JDBC changed what exceptions it throws then, once Hibernate adapted to it, users of Hibernate wouldn't have to change.

What's bad about this example is that the stacktrace information for the original StuffException gets discarded when e goes out of scope, and MyException's stacktrace starts with the location that threw the MyException, making it difficult to find the source of the actual problem. Assigning the old exception to the new exception as its cause would preserve the original stacktrace information:

```
try {
        //Stuff
    } catch(StuffException e) {
        MyException myException = new MyException();
        myException.initCause(e);
        throw myException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception is used to handle something that usually would not occur in the program flow. The point of throwing again an exception is that of changing the type of exception, as in your example. Doing that, you can create a custom exception and throw it inside another exception catch block.

**EDIT**

Here's an example:

Suppose you have a method which works with a Thread. Inside your method you have a delay:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

but if you write just this, you will get an error because the sleep method is declared like this:

```
void java.lang.Thread.sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException
```

So you will have to catch the exception:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(3000);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
//do stuff
}
```

Now, you don't like the InterruptedException and you want to handle it with your own custom exception. But how do you do that since the sleep method only throws that specific exception? The answer is this:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(3000);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
throw new CustomException();
}
```

At this point, if the InterruptedException is raised, it will be catched and it will be raised a CustomException instead.

Comment: thanks, but why not just throw it without having to include the "try catch" statement?

Comment: I've added an example :)

Comment: Thanks, so its basically due to the fact that you have to implement any checked exceptions anyway in order for the code to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Some possible uses of catching then throwing an exception:

- exception translation

  - replacing a checked exception with an unchecked one
  - translating implementation-specific exceptions with some generic exceptions that the caller can handle better
- adding more context / additional info to the exception (e.g. some lowlevel method fails and you want to identify input that it failed on)
- performing an additional action (e.g. logging the error before sending it to the caller)
- handling more complex exception hierarchies

  - e.g. if you want to catch all `IOException`s except for `FileNotFoundException` (which is subtype of `IOException`), you can do this:

    ```
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    ```